# Проблема с блоками. Не могу нормально понять, как мне сделать то, что у меня в голове

Tags: html, css

Ребят, только начинаю изучать html и css, делаю свой третий сайт, так что не судите строго.
Есть два блока и их нужно выровнять, так как на картинке, как мне это сделать?
Через display:flex, justify-content:center не выравнивается, блок приклеен к левому краю.
Если не сложно, объясните как это работает, кратко (заранее спасибо).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.card { 
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    
    width: 370px;
    height: 440px;
    
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.651);
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),
                -15px -15px 30px rgba(135, 133, 138, 0.692);
}
```

```html
    <div class="card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint ullam laborum ipsa voluptatum  quis possimus doloribus maiores cum omnis saepe, voluptatibus corrupti aliquam quas illo. Tempore consequuntur esse impedit molestias.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Блок на картинке расположен там же, где и ваш пример. Вот красные прямоугольники что значат? И зачем пытаетесь центрировать, если на примерах и выделенках это не центр?

Comment: красные прямоугольники значат где по идеи должны располагаться блоки 
а центрировать хочу чтобы блок был размещен по центру по главной оси (горизонтальная ось) а уже с помощью margin-right поставить его в то место где хочу чтобы он располагался или это уже полный к@л и так не правильно?

Comment: marginami в минус делать не правильно, потом будете мучаться с адаптивностью, так как марджин блоки отодвигает за грань дозволенного.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обернуть элемент в отдельный div контейнер

```css
.cardCont {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .card {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;

    padding-top: 40px;
    margin: 0;

    width: 370px;
    height: 440px;

    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.651);
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),
    -15px -15px 30px rgba(135, 133, 138, 0.692);
  }
```

```html
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint ullam laborum ipsa voluptatum  quis possimus doloribus maiores cum omnis saepe, voluptatibus corrupti aliquam quas illo. Tempore consequuntur esse impedit molestias.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: @Enayne, не забываем за кнопку "Принять ответ")

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вам нужен был именно такой вариант. Он и хорошо адаптирован и никаких margin-left: -px;

```css
p { 
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 10px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    
    width: 170px;
    
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.651);
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),
                -15px -15px 30px rgba(135, 133, 138, 0.692);
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 440px;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint ullam laborum ipsa voluptatum  quis possimus doloribus maiores cum omnis saepe, voluptatibus corrupti aliquam quas illo. Tempore consequuntur esse impedit molestias.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint ullam laborum ipsa voluptatum  quis possimus doloribus maiores cum omnis saepe, voluptatibus corrupti aliquam quas illo. Tempore consequuntur esse impedit molestias.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам не нужно иметь два разных блока, вам достаточно правому элементу дать `align-self: flex-end`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson точно, голова не додумалась, я привык верстать блочно.